# VBA cell containing a string inside a loop

Tags: vba, excel, basic

So I'm still very novice at VBA, and I am having some trouble understanding the syntax of it all. I am trying to loop through a column and see if it contains a partial string. If it doesn't, I need the row to be deleted. So far, I have this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim count As Integer

Do While Range("H" & count).Value > 0
    Dim exists As Integer
    exists = InStr(1, Range("H" & count).Value, ".AB", vbTextCompare)

    If exists > 0 Then
        Rows(count).Delete
    Else
        count = count + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

But using this code, I'm getting all sorts of errors. First of which being "Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed". Any knowledge about that?

Comment: You didn't initialize `count` with anything at the start so it equals 0. `H0` is not a valid cell.

Comment: `count` is 0 and there is no row 0.

Comment: OK, so I added in count = 2. But now when I click the button, absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: `Do While Range("H" & count).Value <> ""` - and put `Dim exists As Integer` outside of the loop.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Pls try the below code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim exists As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    lastrow = Range("H" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If InStr(UCase(Range("H" & i).Value), ".AB") > 0 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
            lastrow = lastrow - 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```